# C# - Create new exception without losing stack trace and inner exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method that provides an Exception object and I want to log an error if anything happens in the error handler itself. Here is some pseudocode:

```
public override void OnError(Exception originalException)
{
    try
    {
        // Do work...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // How do I create this exception without losing the stack 
        // trace of e and preserving any inner exceptions that were 
        // in e at the same time including the details of 
        // originalException?
        Exception newException = new Exception(e.Message, originalException);
        Logger.Error("An error occurred", newException);
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to combine originalException and e above into one Exception message to pass to a logger object. I suppose one option would be to create 2 separate log messages but it's not ideal.

Comment: Then why don't you take the original Exception only...?? there's no need to create a new exception then.

Comment: I want to also log what happened in the error filter itself.

Comment: The `originalException` will be accessible via `InnerException` property of `newException` - you can look at the stack trace of the `InnerException`. Otherwise your only option is to re-throw the original exception: `try { ... } catch(ex) { Logger.Error(ex); throw; }`

Comment: To rethrow you can do `throw;`

Comment: You shouldn't be catching so many nested exceptions. Your code should be written to handle specific (not general) exceptions at the point where those exceptions can occur (like file IO exceptions) and that you can handle. Then, if you want a catch all exception handler, put one at the top-level of your code. Otherwise all these general exception handlers just go to making your code buggy.

Comment: How are you logging it? If you simply do `myException.ToString()`, generally that should dump out all exceptions, and their inner exceptions including stack traces for everything automatically. EDIT: What you have there is fine (assuming you're wrapping it with a more relevant/appropriate exception and it makes sense for your actual scenario); passing it in as an inner exception should have it dump out logging information fine. EDIT: Here's an example showing what I mean, it captures the stack trace of both exceptions: http://rextester.com/CXO53502

Comment: Chris Sinclair: The issue is that originalException is an exception object that is provided to me as an argument in an OnException handler (this is a MVC application and I have my own custom error attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap multiple exceptions:

```
public override void OnError(Exception originalException)
{
    try
    {
        // Do work...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var exs = new AggregateException(originalException, e);
        Logger.Error("An error occurred", exs);
    }
}
```

EDIT: If `Logger` doesn't record contents of the `InnerException` property (or `InnerExceptions` in this case) then seems the only option is multiple calls to `Logger.Error`.